# Which branch to push to after git rebase

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-push

In my workflow I have `master` and a remote branch `branch1`. I branched out from `branch1` and created `branch2`. I did my work in `branch2` and `branch1` carried on having more things commited by other devs. Once I was done I commited my changes to `branch2` rebased my changes on top of `branch1`'s latest commit. Git log in `branch2` shows my commit on top of `branch1`'s latest commit so all looks good there. However in `branch1`'s `git log` my commits are not seen. Do I have to do a `git push` after I do a `git rebase`? If yes, then In this case, do I push to `branch1` or `branch2`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your changes are not reflected in `branch1` because they are not part of `branch1`.

In your case, `branch2` comes *after* `branch1`, so you see both. But `branch1` is therefore *before* `branch2`. From `branch1`'s perspective, `branch2` hasn't happened yet.

What you are seeing is correct. If you are using the `master` branch as your "live" or "final" branch, you could merge `branch2` into master:

```
git checkout master && git merge branch2
```

This would bring your changes from both branches into `master`.

---

Also: The fact that `branch1` is remote and `branch2` is local doesn't really matter in this case. The commits themselves are in both places (because git is distributed). The "branches" are just names given to different commits to make it easy to manage them.

Comment: Can I instead do `git checkout branch1 && git merge branch2` ? We dont merge to master before a bunch of checks and stuff...

Comment: Yeah you can do that, sure. That will move `branch1` forward in the tree (fast-forward) to be where `branch2` is, effectively making the two branches the same (pointing to the same commit).

Comment: Site note: a gui is really helpful in visualizing this stuff, especially when learning git. My fav right now is https://www.gitkraken.com/ but ymmv.

Comment: How does the remote `branch1` get updated though? If I log into github and see the pull request for `branch1`, it does not show my rebased commits...

Comment: Ah I see. After you merge, push branch1. That way, origin/branch1 will match local branch1.

Comment: Thanks. 1 last question, what would happen if I dont do a merge and instead on `branch2` I do `git push branch1 branch2` ?

Comment: Push/pull are for interacting with remote repos. If you are working with local branches, you want rebase and/or merge.